# Keyboard combination to signal end of standard in to Windows Console

Tags: windows, keyboard, console

Is there a keyboard combination I can use to signal to the Windows Console that Standard Input has finished?  I'm trying to use a command line app that can accept input from the stdin which may be just typing at the console but when I type at the console I can't work out how to tell the app that I've finished my input so it actually then processes it.

I assume there's some key combination for this? (which may be app specific?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`<Control>+<Z>` followed by `<Enter>` ends input.